# What is the difference between Spring Tool Suite 3 and 4?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I want to study Spring. In the case of STS (Spring Tool Suite) 3, there is "Spring legacy Project". 4 has a "Spring Starter Project", is it the same?

When I asked the Internet, people say "just use version 3".

1. What is the difference between version 3 and version 4?
2. Is "Spring Starter Project" and "Spring Legacy Project" the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.What is the difference between version 3 and version 4?

Version 4.0 is the latest major release of the Spring Framework and the first to fully support Java 8 and few new features.[[more]](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html)

> 2. Is "Spring Starter Project" and "Spring Legacy Project" the same thing?

Technically both are same spring project's. But they have some difference in configuration and build areas.

**Spring Starter Project**- Helps to create the spring boot project.(Spring Boot is basically an extension of the Spring framework which eliminated the boilerplate configurations required for setting up a Spring application.)

**Spring Legacy Project** - Helps to create the spring maven project. In which all the required configuration like servlet context,web,.. need to be configured manually either by using xml file or java classes.

Take a look at this page to know more about the difference between [spring vs spring boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-vs-spring-boot)

If you are going to start learning spring from beginning, my suggestion is use **Spring Starter Project** because in **Spring boot** project setup is so simple, you can start coding with zero manual configuration.

Answer (score 5):

For a more detailed introduction of the Spring Tools 4, please take a look at the blog post from the initial GA release of the Spring Tools 4:

https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/25/spring-tools-4-ga-released

There is no direct relation between the version numbers of the Spring Framework itself and the Spring Tools. In general, the Spring Tools 4 as well as the older Spring Tool Suite 3 support various Spring versions, ranging from Spring Framework 3 up to Spring Framework 5.2 and beyond.

I would strongly recommend to start with learning Spring by starting with Spring Boot, not the Spring Legacy projects. This is the way modern Spring applications are being built nowadays... :-)